# AndroLua on Lollipop: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call static int org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaJavaAPI.javaNew(int, java.lang.Class)

Tags: android, lua, luajava

I want to use AndroLua as library in my Android application.

Everything goes well on Android version except Android 5.x (Lollipop)

But my app crashed under Lollipop if I call juajava.new lua function.
The logcat shows

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call static int org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaJavaAPI.javaNew(int, java.lang.Class) on class java.lang.Class<java.lang.Class>
```

How can I solve the problem?
Or is there alternative to run lua in Android?

Comment: I give up the luajava.new function. Instead, create new object in java and return the new created object to lua.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jasonsantos/luajava/issues/10 fixes the bug:

> Calling luajava.new(...) produce the following error on Android ART:
>   A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN
>   APPLICATION: can't call static int
>   org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaJavaAPI.javaNew(int, java.lang.Class)
>   with class java.lang.Class A/art:
>   art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] in call to CallStaticIntMethod
>
> After some code review, I figured out the problem. In luajava.c, line
>   1377: ret = ( *javaEnv )->CallStaticIntMethod( javaEnv , clazz ,
>   method , (jint)stateIndex , classInstance ); "clazz" is not the object
>   we want here. It should be: ret = ( *javaEnv )->CallStaticIntMethod(
>   javaEnv , luajava_api_class , method , (jint)stateIndex ,
>   classInstance );
>
> Moreover, I think, line 1371: if ( clazz == NULL || method == NULL )
>   should be: if ( luajava_api_class == NULL || method == NULL )
>
> Nir.